# Как добавить на задний фон заставку

Tags: qt

Как добавить на задний фон заставку ?
Хочу добавить на задний фон картинку .png в окне 
mainWindow и dialog. Как правильно это сделать?

Добавил код в styleSheet.
    QWidget{
    background-image: url("/image/layer.png") no-repeat right bottom;
    }

Фон должен быть на заднем плане а тут получается что на каждом lable и graphicsview он отобразился.

[image: То что хочу видить]

[image: То что получилось]

Comment: Я не программирую qt, но знаю что там есть метод draw. он отвечает за рисование окна. может с помощью него можно картинку нарисовать.

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/1378/is-it-possible-to-set-a-background-image-to-a-widget/5

Comment: А как сделать фон у QMainWindow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пропишите stylesheet. изображение необходимо разместить в ресурс

пример:

мне надо было разместить фоном логотип в правый нижний угол виджета дерева.
при этом надо было зафиксировать положение чтобы фон не двигался при скролле.
в редакторе задал stylesheet:

```
QTreeView{
background: url(:/ico/background) no-repeat right bottom;
 background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
border-bottom-width: 5;
border-right-width: 15;
}
```

получилось так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополнительно.

Следует помнить что стили наследуются на потомков (с учетом объектного наследования). Поэтому в вашем примере стиль для QWidget будет распространяться на всех потомков (поскольку все они являются наследниками QWidget). Чтобы этого избежать, задавайте стили для конкретных виджетов, а не для всего окна, либо указывайте конкретный класс: QTreeWidget, QFrame и т.п., либо используйте селекторы. Например:

```
QWidget[objectName="centralWidget"]{ background-image: url(":/img/bg") no-repeat right bottom; } 
QWidget[objectName="myFrame"]{ background-color: #ff0000; } 
QLineEdit{ background-color: #00ff00; } 
QWidget[enabled="false"]{ background-color: #0000ff; }
```

Comment: Tatarincev поправил вопрос.

Comment: Вы прописали стиль для QWidget, а все потомки являются его наследниками и поэтому наследуют и стиль. Дополнил ответ. Посмотрите

Comment: Мне кажется это очень много сожрет ресурсов пк. Есть более простой способ?

Comment: Все будет нормально. У вас же браузер не тормозит, а тут таблицы стилей куда как сложнее

Comment: У меня ARM 454 МГЦ 1 ядро.

Answer (score 0):

Если кому надо решение:

```
   QPixmap bkgnd("./image/layer.png");
   bkgnd = bkgnd.scaled(size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
   QPalette p = palette();
   p.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bkgnd);
   setPalette(p);
```